# How to sort a list of users closest to you by distance?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, firebase, core-location

This is more of a swift question in general, but if it helps: I'm storing all of these users in Firebase.

So I am trying to be conservative with my Firebase calls, and I am just curious what the best option would be if I wanted to display the 100 closest users sorted by distance.

I'm familiar with calculating the distance by radii with CoreLocation, but I'm thinking of the backend. Is the best way really to pull all of the users from Firebase, slap them in a dictionary, and sort them by coordinate key? I'm failing to see an alternative.

Thanks guys!

Comment: If you're storing the users in the Firebase Database, the best approach is to use [Geofire](https://github.com/firebase/geofire-objc). This library uses geo-hashes to allow efficient querying by distance on the server.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a little strange. But here you can vospolzovatsya sorted by value.

You can put the label for each user from a distance and write firevase. Tags can be updated when you run the application or site. You just have to add to the table distance.

The example will be clearer.

[image]

The query will look like this

`const ref = firebase.database().ref('Distance');`

```
ref.orderByChild('distanceFrend').limitToFirst(100).on('value', snap => { .... }
```

You will get a list sorted by distance. At first the closest.

I hope the example will help to solve the problem

Comment: Example of a request for the web. I'm not familiar with SWIFT

Comment: Thanks so much! So, basically, you're suggested to have a distance object for each user, and have all the users distance from the user hierarchy it belongs to?

Comment: You can say yes.

There are plenty of opportunities for implementation. It depends on what eventually want to get.

The main thing here, to send data in the form of distances from the user.